# Iteratively add sub shortcodes to php array

Tags: shortcode, content, array

I have this shortcode structure:

```
[component]
   [type1]some content[/type1]
   [type2]some more content[/type2]
   ...
   [typeN]some other content[/typeN]
[/component]
```

I would like to have the `$content` of the sub shortcodes stored in an array. What I am doing at the moment is, in their function, I pass `$content` to a global variable and then create an array out of them, but it is not very elegant.

Also, I cannot have them as attributes of the main shortcode tag as this:

```
[component type1="some content" type2="some more content"]
```

as I need to have the attributes on new lines for readability - something I'm trying to get addressed here: [wpautop() when shortcode attributes are on new lines break args array](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/wpautop-when-shortcode-attributes-are-on-new-lines-break-args-array)

EDIT - I'm not looking for a list-like structure, but to have these values in a key-value array to populate a complex markup, and also use the array as a JSON object in my javascript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure appears to be very list like. The reason you're running into difficulties is because you're trying to fix a fix, which is never a good thing. Instead I would suggest you seek alternative solutions to your problem.

For example, instead it would be more logical to use something like:

```
<ul class="component">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
</ul>
```

Using this kind of structure you can implement everything from JQuery accordions, tabs, blocks of content, etc etc

```
.component {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.component > li {
    /* style each list element here
}
```

Or using ol even. Then [coupling this with editor styles to mark it out as different](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) from a normal unordered list.

To further differentiate it, use an extra button using TinyMCE.

```
function add_component_button() {
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_component_tinymce_plugin');
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_component_button');
   }
}

function register_component_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "|", "componentlist");
   return $buttons;
}

function add_component_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
   $plugin_array['componentlist'] = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/custom/editor_plugin.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}

add_action('init', 'add_component_button');

function my_refresh_mce($ver) {
  $ver += 3;
  return $ver;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'my_refresh_mce');
```

Here's editor_plugin.js:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.componentul', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('componentul', {
                title : 'componentul',
                image : url+'/component.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<ul class="component"><li>Start typing here</li></ul>');
                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
        getInfo : function() {
            return {
                longname : "Component UL",
                author : 'Tom J Nowell',
                authorurl : 'http://tomjn.com/',
                infourl : 'http://tomjn.com/',
                version : "1.0"
            };
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('componentul', tinymce.plugins.componentul);
})();
```

Comment: thanks, this is an impressive answer that deserves a +1 at least. I probably had to be more specific - I am having a list-like structure but my pure target is to get a key-value array, as I need it its contents to both populate a complex markup structure, and create a JSON object with the same values to be used in a javascript method.

Comment: `var components = $('.component > li ');`?

Comment: Perhaps if you're pulling it in via AJAX too then it would be best to use post meta instead, and simply do a single shortcode like `[displaycomponents]` rather than have the data structure itself in the content ( and all the problems it brings with it )

Comment: I agree, I think that a custom post is probably the best way for my case. thanks for your help!